# dataTables filter box lost focus when type on it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using dataTables jquery plugin on a table showed with bootstrap modal plugin. When I type on dataTables filter box it lost focus and I need to click inside it to type again. This behavior does not occur outside of modal plugin so I think the problem is the interaction between dataTables and modal.

How can I solve this problem?

I have surfed on internet but I could not find an answer.

Thanks for your help!

Note: I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.3 and dataTables 1.10.0

Comment: Did you find a way around this? I have a similar issue, yet nothing to do with bootstrap or modal plugin. But the same problem related to searchbox losing focus (only in mobile) every time a character is typed and the table refreshed.

Comment: Hi, I did not find a solution. In my case I have to remove the filter box and create a `select` element as a filter for my data.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. The modal of bootstrap have a little delay, and the modal gets the focus faster than the input.focus(). If not work try more than 500.
I fixed it doing this:

```
var input = $('selectorYourDatatable input');
setTimeout(function(){
    input.focus();
}, 500);
```

I hope this be useful.